# Is there a way to dynamically allocate variables in this SCSS fade scheme?

Tags: variables, sass

My end product here is a situation where I can have different levels of a fade effect on my links and hover. So in this situation, it won't matter what color I chose for theme background, the links and hover will change to match. This will also also allow for using the fade variable to style any other element.

I setup a CodePen to demonstrate this http://codepen.io/SiscoKid/pen/dMzXzJ.

I would like to clean this up and also extend it to include Internet Explorer functionality.

```
// Fade
$fade-base: #fff;
$fade0: rgba($fade-base, 0);
$fade1: rgba($fade-base, 0.1);
$fade2: rgba($fade-base, 0.2);
$fade3: rgba($fade-base, 0.3);
$fade4: rgba($fade-base, 0.4);
$fade5: rgba($fade-base, 0.5);
$fade6: rgba($fade-base, 0.6);
$fade7: rgba($fade-base, 0.7);
$fade8: rgba($fade-base, 0.8);
$fade9: rgba($fade-base, 0.9);
$fade10: rgba($fade-base, 1);
//
// Color
$test-color: #f00;
$theme-base: #483; // CHANGE ME
$title-color: $fade5;
//
// Links
@mixin links() {
  a {
    color: $fade3;
    &:hover {
      color: $fade1;
    }
  }
}
//
// Body
@mixin main() {
  @include links;
  background-color: $theme-base;
}

.main {
    @include main();
}
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
color: $fade(0.3);
```

Instead of:

```
color: $fade3;
```

So what is the best way to achieve this expanded functionality?

I have done some research and found that we cannot dynamically assign these variables.

[dynamic variables #1450](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1450)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to develop a function to do this for me. I have also expanded this idea to include background-color fade accessibility.

```
//
// Fade
@function fades($percentage) {
  @return lighten(255, (1-$percentage)*5%);
}

@mixin fade($type, $percentage) {
  @if $type==cl {
    color: rgba(#fff, $percentage);
  }
  @if $type==bg {
    background-color: rgba(#fff, $percentage);
  }
}
//
// Title
.title {
  @include fade(cl, .5);
}
```

I am still unsure about expanding this for IE, as well as, dynamically creating gradient type classes. However, I think these might be topics for other questions.

Here is a link to the working CodePen.
[Fade SCSS Function and Mixin](https://codepen.io/SiscoKid/pen/ONjWoG)

Thanks again to petehotchkiss for his feedback on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure exactly what the end product is your trying to achieve here, but it does feel like it's creating needless CSS code.

Whats wrong with

```
&:hover {
  background-color: rgba($fade-base, 0.9);
}
```

I'm not sure why you need to add a layer of complexity by wrapping it in a method?

Comment: I made an update to my original post with a CodePen to demonstrate my end result. Thanks for your feedback and I hope my update brings to light what I am trying to do here. I apologize for the initial lack of information.
Unfortunately though,  I think that typing
`&:hover 
    { background-color: rgba($fade-base, 0.9); 
}`
over and over is a little redundant. In the long run I definitely would type less by using my current setup.
Also, do you have any ideas about integrating Internet Explorer support in to this?